# Quotient of a Lie algebra by a subalgebra - what is it?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, group-actions

[Cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3774599/214353) from math.SE (asked there 20 days ago).

The quotient $G/H$ of a group $G$ by its subgroup $H$ has a $G$-action - every transitive $G$-set is of this form.

However, the quotient space $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ by its subalgebra $\mathfrak h$ is just a vector space. By analogy with the group case, I am trying to figure out whether it is still "special" in some way.

If $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of a Lie group or an algebraic group $G$ with some representation $V$, and $\mathfrak h$ is the Lie algebra of the stabilizer $H=G^v$ of some vector $v\in V$, then there is a way to identify the tangent space of the orbit $Gv$ at $v$ with the space $\mathfrak gv=\{gv\mid g\in\mathfrak g\}$, so that the surjective map $\mathfrak g\twoheadrightarrow\mathfrak gv$ sending $g$ to $gv$ has kernel $\mathfrak h$. Note that although $\mathfrak g$ acts on $V$, the subspace $\mathfrak gv$ is not in general closed under the $\mathfrak g$-action (and does not in general contain $v$).

So one possibility to relate spaces $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ to quotients like $G/H$ would be to ask whether there exists a $\mathfrak g$-representation $V$ and a vector $v\in V$ such that $\mathfrak h=\{g\in\mathfrak g\mid gv=0\}$ and there is an isomorphism $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h\cong\mathfrak gv$ compatible with the quotient maps $\mathfrak g\twoheadrightarrow\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ sending $g$ to $g+\mathfrak h$ and $\mathfrak g\twoheadrightarrow\mathfrak gv$ sending $g$ to $gv$.

Can this (or maybe something better) be always done?

As mentioned in a comment by [Torsten Schoeneberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/96384/torsten-schoeneberg) to that math.SE question, if $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $\mathfrak h$ is the Lie algebra of a subgroup $H$, then one can identify $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ with the tangent space to $G/H$. I would like to work with algebras only, without invoking groups, but even using groups I am not sure how to proceed from there. What $V$ to take? What $v$?

Comment: $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$ is “special” in that it is an $H$-module (under the isotropy representation), hence also an $\mathfrak h$-module (under the infinitesimal isotropy representation).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Yes, this was also mentioned in that comment by Torsten. It can be seen without mentioning groups also, $h(g+\mathfrak h)=[h,g]+\mathfrak h$ is unambiguous. But is it also $\mathfrak gv$ for some $v$ in some representation of $\mathfrak g$?

Comment: There is the [Mostow-Palais theorem](//mathoverflow.net/a/150139)...

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I see. So even the group case is not completely clear then - there is a condition of having finitely many orbits only, which in the algebra context means additional restriction of having $v$ with $\mathfrak gv$ being a subrepresentation of $\mathfrak g$ (I think).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_connection

Comment: This is always true for algebraic subgroups, if you allow a vector to be replaced by a line; it is Theorem 5.1 of Borel.  I thought it was due to some other famous name (Chevalley?), but it is not mentioned in the history.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, Chevalley’s Theorem (Humphreys’ §[11.2](//books.google.com/books?id=7hTTBwAAQBAJ&ots=PaSFh6k-1a&pg=PA80)).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I only realize that it is highly relevant. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I am trying to modify the proof of the Chevalley theorem to make it group-free. Seemingly one has to start with considering the centralizer $Z$ of $\mathfrak h$ in the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak g)$ of $\mathfrak g$, generate the $\mathfrak g$-submodule $W$ of $U(\mathfrak g)$ by a generating set of $Z$, and then take $\Lambda^d(W)$ where $d$ is the dimension of $W\cap Z$...?

Comment: @LSpice Which text do you mean?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369698/quotient-of-a-lie-algebra-by-a-subalgebra-what-is-it#comment934272_369698), [Borel - Linear algebraic groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6).

Comment: @LSpice Thanks, could not find it on the first attempt (became confused by the numbering scheme, apparently)